# Filter with wrong total actual work

Tags: ms-project-2013

I have a problem with filtering in Microsoft Project 2013. When I create a filter based on some criteria, the results doesn't show correct total work and actual work. In fact, it sums actual work of all tasks and ignores the filter. In some filters, group by resource is useful but in this case group by is incorrect.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

In Project, filters do not show the sum of just the filtered tasks.  You'll need to use groups to show summary data by group.  If you are trying to group by resource assigned, try grouping the Task Usage view, not the Gantt view.